# How to create custom class Loading view using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, loading

I am implementing loading concept by custom class loading view. I need to use this custom class by using simple `self.show()` and `self.dismiss` function. Here, I achieved this concept by using `UIActivityController` within `UIAlertView` but I need to do this using custom class.

Below code what I achieved by using `UIActivityController` within `UIAlertView`

```
func loadinHubShow() {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
                loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
                loadingIndicator.style = UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.gray
                loadingIndicator.startAnimating();
                alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
                present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

func loadinHubDismiss() {
     dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

How to change this to custom class `loading view`. I don’t want to use `UIActivityController` within `UIAlertView`, Alternatively need to create same look and feel `UI design` by `UIView`.

[image]

Comment: check this. https://blog.usejournal.com/generic-loader-1858b093ac6b

Answer (score 6):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public class Indicator {

    public static let sharedInstance = Indicator()
    var blurImg = UIImageView()
    var indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    private init()
    {
        blurImg.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        blurImg.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        blurImg.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        blurImg.alpha = 0.5
        indicator.style = .whiteLarge
        indicator.center = blurImg.center
        indicator.startAnimating()
        indicator.color = .red
    }

    func showIndicator(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async( execute: {

            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(self.blurImg)
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(self.indicator)
        })
    }
    func hideIndicator(){

        DispatchQueue.main.async( execute:
            {
                self.blurImg.removeFromSuperview()
                self.indicator.removeFromSuperview()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: how to call this from `MainViewController` also `indicator.color = constants.appColor.kBlueColor` showing error `Use of unresolved identifier 'constants'`.  It will provide output like above I mentioned Image UI?

Comment: Create an Instance of class Indicator from your view controller. call the method showIndicator()

Comment: Call this from your view controller let activityInstance = Indicator()                                         activityInstance.showIndicator()

Comment: indicator.color = //add color of your choice i.e UIColor.red
You can use like this: Indicator.sharedInstance.showIndicator()
For hiding use : Indicator.sharedInstance.hideIndicator()
include in main thread:
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        Indicator.sharedInstance.showIndicator()
}
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        Indicator.sharedInstance.hideIndicator()
}

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit

class Loader: UIView {

var view: UIView!
@IBOutlet fileprivate weak var blurView: UIVisualEffectView!
@IBOutlet fileprivate weak var loader: UIActivityIndicatorView!

var targetView: UIView?

required init(forView view: UIView) {
    super.init(frame: view.bounds)
    targetView = view
    self._setup()
    targetView?.addSubview(self)
}
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    _setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self._setup()
}

private func _setup() {
    view = _loadViewFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

    addSubview(view)
}

private func _loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
    let nibView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView

    return nibView
}

func showLoading(withCompletion completion: (() -> Swift.Void)? = nil) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { 
    }) { _ in
        completion?()
    }
}

func hideLoading() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
    }) { _ in
        self.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
}
```

You can call below functions in your ViewController

```
func showLoading() {
    if self.view.subviews.map({ $0 is Loader }).contains(true) {
        return
    }
    let loader = Loader(forView: self.view)
    loader.showLoading()
}

func hideLoading() {
    for view in self.view.subviews {
        if let view = view as? Loader {
            view.hideLoading()
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to call this from `MainVIewController`? It will provide output like above I mentioned Image UI?

Comment: if I call `self.showLoading()` getting crash `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB`

Comment: You have to create xib file with swift class provided above and connect UIActivityIndicatorView outlet with above class

Comment: is there anything simplest solution without using .xib?

Comment: This is very simple solution for your query. you have to create simply a xib file with class and connect outlet.

Comment: You can use any library if you don't want to use above solution. you can use this below library. 

https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView

Comment: is there anything solution without .xib because already apps size going very high. So I would like to make this done by coding.

Answer (score 0):

**You can customize the below code according to your needs**

```
func showActivityIndicatory(uiView: UIView) {
    var container: UIView = UIView()
    container.frame = uiView.frame
    container.center = uiView.center
    container.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(0xffffff, alpha: 0.3)

    var loadingView: UIView = UIView()
    loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)
    loadingView.center = uiView.center
    loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(0x444444, alpha: 0.7)
    loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
    loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    var actInd: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    actInd.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
    actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle =
                UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
    actInd.center = CGPointMake(loadingView.frame.size.width / 2,
                loadingView.frame.size.height / 2);
    loadingView.addSubview(actInd)
    container.addSubview(loadingView)
    uiView.addSubview(container)
    actInd.startAnimating()
}
```

Comment: you need to use only the code which suits your design. Have a Base view(Container). Add a label and an activity monitor as sub views. Initially you will feel difficulty.once you get to know how to use UIView it will be easy

Comment: in the above code the loading view is holding the activity indicator. and the container view has both loading view and actInd as subviews. Just add a UILabel and position it accordingly